# What's the meaning of the ethereum Parity console output lines?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, parity-io

Parity doesn't seem to have any documentation on what it's console output means. At least none that I've found which admittedly doesn't mean a whole lot. Can anyone give me a breakdown of the meaning of the following line?

```
2018-03-09 00:05:12 UTC Syncing #4896969 61ee…bdad     2 blk/s  508 tx/s  16 Mgas/s    645+    1 Qed  #4897616   17/25 peers      4 MiB chain  135 MiB db   42 MiB queue    5 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,  0 req/s, 182 µs
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why document when you can just [read code](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/blob/master/parity/informant.rs#L302)? (bleh)

> 2018-03-09 00:05:12 UTC(1) Syncing #4896969(2) 61ee…bdad(3)     2 blk/s(4)  508 tx/s(5)  16 Mgas/s(6)    645+(7)    1(8) Qed  #4897616(9)   17/25 peers(10)      4 MiB chain(11)  135 MiB db(12)   42 MiB queue(13)    5 MiB sync(14)  RPC:  0 conn(15),  0 req/s(16), 182 µs(17)

1. Timestamp
2. Best block number (latest **verified** block number)
3. Best block hash
4. Blocks downloaded per second
5. Transactions downloaded per second
6. Millions of gas processed per second
7. Unverified queue size
8. Verified queue size
9. Latest block number
10. Number of active peer nodes/number of total peer nodes
11. Blockchain header cache size
12. Blockchain state cache size
13. Queue cache size
14. Node sync metadata cache size
15. Number of open RPC sessions to your node
16. RPC requests per second
17. Approximate roundtrip ping

Answer (score 0):

Now the answer to this question is also included in Parity's FAQ. It provides a comprehensive explanation of different command line output:

[What does Parity's command line output mean?](https://openethereum.github.io/wiki/FAQ#what-does-paritys-command-line-output-mean)